# Unbalanced Phono output from (Pioneer DDJ-SB2) to balanced XLR mic level

Tags: mixing, gear, setup, live-sound

I'm playing a gig in a few days where I need to connect my Pioneer DDJ-SB2 to a XLR mic level input. Assuming that the XLR is balanced.

Can anyone suggest the best way to achieve that? I was thinking either:

a) Behringer DI400P Ultra-DI Passive DI Box -> Use twin phono to jack/TRS converter -> box -> XLR balanced

b)  -> Twin phono input, balanced TRS to XLR converter adaptor.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Both of the options you listed have drawbacks.

a) Assuming a balanced XLR, this will take your stereo turntable output, invert the phase one of the channels, and leave you with a very poor sounding mono signal missing bits of varying bits of the audio spectrum.

b) Will not match impedance or input signal requirements, and it will will likely leave you with a noisy low-intensity signal going into the sound system.

I recommend a (somewhat pricey, but extremely useful) stereo DI like the Radial [J-33](http://Radial%20J33%E2%84%A2%20-%20Turntable%20DI%20-%20Radial%20Engineering) or [ProAV1](http://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/ProAV1?adpos=1o4&creative=54989263441&device=c&matchtype=&network=g&product_id=ProAV1&gclid=CjwKEAjwkJfABRDnhbPlx6WI4ncSJADMQqxdAiGGkm6L_gVwrwRgstYxykynpThSVY-ULLPkMkieZhoCYmjw_wcB), but failing those, using two cheaper "mono" DIs (one for each channel, left/right) with RCA to 1/4 TS adapters has worked fine for me in the past.

Comment: There are many cheap stereo-DI boxes that work perfectly well for gigs, so I'd always go this route. Have an upvote.